# sine addition formula to solve x

Tags: trigonometry

> a) Write $\sin x \cos 20^\circ + \cos x \sin 20^\circ$ in the form $\sin(A + B)$.
>
> b) Hence solve $\sin x \cos 20^\circ + \cos x \sin 20^\circ = 0.6, 0^{\circ} \leq x \le 360^{\circ} $

a) $\sin(x + 20)$

b) $\sin x \cos 20 + \cos x \sin 20 = 0.6$

I am not sure how to proceed for part b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac35=\sin x\cos 20+\sin20\cos x=\sin(x+20)\iff$$

$$ x+20=\arcsin\frac35\;\text{or}\;x+20=180-\arcsin\frac35$$

Comment: Is it possible to solve witout using arcsin?  I have not covered this.  Also where did $\frac{3}{5}$ come from?

Comment: (1) The function $\;\arcsin\;$ is what your pocket calculator denotes by $\;\sin^{-1}=\;$ the inverse function of sine, and it fulfills that $\;\sin x=a\iff x=\arcsin a\;$, when within the appropiate domains, of course. (2) It's just $\;0.6=\frac35\;$

Comment: thank you for the explanation